# $emit object to parent component, and push to array. Objects in array continue to be reactive, why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm trying to make a function where users can added multiple resume posts (from child component) to an array (in parent).
The problem is, every object I push to parent array stays reactive with the child form/object. So if I for example clear the form in child component, the Object I pushed to the parent array gets all it's values cleared as well. How to I emit and push the post-object to parent array and stop it from being reactive, so I can add new/more resume posts?

**CreateProfile.vue**

```
<template>
    <ResumePostInput :resume_posts="form.resume_posts" @resumeHandler="handleResume"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
         form: {
              resume_posts: []
         }
    }
    methods: {
        handleResume(post) {
            this.form.resume_posts.push(post)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**ResumePostInput.vue**

```
<template
-- Input fields binded to post object --
</template>

<script>  
export default {
    emits: ["resumeHandler"],
    props: {
         resume_posts: Array
    },
    data() {
        return {
            post: {
                title: '',
                sub_title: '',
                text: '',
                year_from: '',
                year_to: '',
                type: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addResume() {
            this.$emit("resumeHandler", this.post)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is this vue 2 or 3? The question shouldn't have both tags. It does not just continue to be reactive. It's the same object, it's passed by reference. If you don't want it to be affected in another place, create a copy

Comment: vue3. How do I make a non reactive copy? If I do something like let copy = this.post and then emit copy, it's still reactive

Comment: See this image https://giphy.com/gifs/8k0fixwuiQQBTt8hx5

Answer (score 1):

It's not the problem that the object is reactive but that it's the same object because objects are passed by reference in JavaScript. If it's modified in one place, it's modified everywhere.

In order to avoid this, the object needs to be explicitly copied. For shallow object this can be done with object spread:

```
this.$emit("resumeHandler", {...this.post})
```

For deeply nested objects, multiple spreads or third-party clone function can be used.

Comment: Thanks. Had no idea about this, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

you emit unknown property, it's a `post`, not `posts`

and learn about JS object, there are copy by reference & value

maybe you just need to update your addResume method like this

```
   addResume() {
      const post = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.post))
      this.$emit("resumeHandler", post)
   }
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, I typed wrong when I wrote this post. It's supposed to be post. But that's not the problem I'm having.

Comment: Yeah, The JSON.parse/stringify did the trick, thanks! I'm new to Javascript :)